# Skeleton framework - css list spacing

Tags: html, css, list, alignment

I'm trying to float my navigation at the top much more to left around 200px atleast more towards the end of the line that can been seen below. Everytime I apply a margin or padding it pushes the navigation to go under each other even though there is loads of room, could anyone take a look at my code.

means alot thanks,

I always find things easier with firebug so I uploaded it here http://xronn.co.uk/hosting/

Thanks again!

Comment: Simplify your HTML and CSS (to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)/representative demo) and post the relevant code *here*. And, ideally, a [live demo at JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, that we can play, and experiment, with.

Comment: You want the navigation above the logo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean to the left or the right? If you mean to the left, then there is a huge image in the way that is blocking the navigation menu. If you mean to the right then you can always increase the width of the navigation div and apply a `float: right;` css rule to the `ul` (to the #nav element).

Comment: Sorry I did mean right, i'm gonna test this now thanks for putting both!

Answer (score 0):

Switch the places of the navigation and logo `divs`, like that:

```
<div class="seven columns">navigation menu</div>
<div class="five columns">logo</div>
```

This should push the navigation to the left. Furthermore make sure the navigation `div` is more that `seven` otherwise the logo will end up next to the navigation menu.